# How to fix an error with Unity NavMesh Directional Path

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm following a tutorial that shows how to display a navigation path for a player to follow in Unity. It wasn't working for me so I decided to download his source code but now I'm getting an index out of bounds error while he is not. What could I possibly be doing wrong?

[image: enter image \here]

In the attached image, there should be a blue pathway to the yellow ring from the player. The tutorial I followed can be found here alongside his source code.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scaBHHFKLL0&t=528s

```cs
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class CollectableSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Collectable Prefab;
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform Player;
    [SerializeField]
    private LineRenderer Path;
    [SerializeField]
    private float PathHeightOffset = 1.25f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float SpawnHeightOffset = 1.5f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float PathUpdateSpeed = 0.25f;

    private Collectable ActiveInstance;
    private NavMeshTriangulation Triangulation;
    private Coroutine DrawPathCoroutine;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Triangulation = NavMesh.CalculateTriangulation();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        SpawnNewObject();
    }

    public void SpawnNewObject()
    {
        ActiveInstance = Instantiate(Prefab,
            Triangulation.vertices[Random.Range(0, Triangulation.vertices.Length)] + Vector3.up * SpawnHeightOffset,
            Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0)
        );
        ActiveInstance.Spawner = this;

        if (DrawPathCoroutine != null)
        {
            StopCoroutine(DrawPathCoroutine);
        }

        DrawPathCoroutine = StartCoroutine(DrawPathToCollectable());
    }

    private IEnumerator DrawPathToCollectable()
    {
        WaitForSeconds Wait = new WaitForSeconds(PathUpdateSpeed);
        NavMeshPath path = new NavMeshPath();

        while (ActiveInstance != null)
        {
            if (NavMesh.CalculatePath(Player.position, ActiveInstance.transform.position, NavMesh.AllAreas, path))
            {
                Path.positionCount = path.corners.Length;

                for (int i = 0; i < path.corners.Length; i++)
                {
                    Path.SetPosition(i, path.corners[i] + Vector3.up * PathHeightOffset);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError($"Unable to calculate a path on the NavMesh between {Player.position} and {ActiveInstance.transform.position}!");
            }

            yield return Wait;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well verticies.count could be 5 if there are 5 but then you add "up" wouldnt that then make that 6? Therefore out of bounds.

Comment: @BugFinder the exception comes from `Triangulation.vertices[Random.Range(0, Triangulation.vertices.Length)]` ... the only situation for this to happen would be that `Triangulation.vertices` is an empty array with `0` elements ...